# Can we determine the carrier/operator for an Android device whos sim has been removed?

Tags: android

For a GSM Android device, whose sim card has been removed, is there any way to detect which carrier the device was previously running on, or perhaps sold by?  I am most concerned with detecting phones who have the same Build.Device and are sold by multiple different carrier/operators.

Most method's of carrier/operator detection seem to depend on it currently being connected to the network, or a SIM being present.

Comment: Do the Android-based devices undergo branding? (This is an annoying aspect of many "dumb phones" with SIM cards.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check the `Build.FINGERPRINT` string. It may not be 100% reliable, but most carriers put their name on the first section of the string: `$(PRODUCT_BRAND)`.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.html

The FINGERPRINT format is the following:

`$(PRODUCT_BRAND)/$(PRODUCT_NAME)/$(PRODUCT_DEVICE)/$(TARGET_BOOTLOADER_BOARD_NAME):$(PLATFORM_VERSION)/$(BUILD_ID)/$(BUILD_NUMBER):$(TARGET_BUILD_VARIANT)/$(BUILD_VERSION_TAGS)`

Of those, `$(BUILD_ID)` is specific for carrier/build/region.

**Of course, none of this will work in unbranded devices or in devices with custom ROMs**, since they are not bound to any carrier without a sim. For those two cases, I believe there is no way to determine anything besides checking the sim, simply **because there is nothing to check.**